# Android layout: button's vertical padding

Tags: android, android-layout, button, padding

How can I make my button's vertical padding small enough?

Here is an example:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:text="New Button"/>
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

As you can see, there is still vertical padding.
How can I adjust it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the minimum height to a smaller value:

```
android:minHeight=5dp
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I've event set 0dp for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your xml, it should remove the vertical padding of the font:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried what @Iulian Vărzaru said and that removed a little bit of that padding.

By the way, i think that padding is coming from your `android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"`

Here you can see with @Iulian Vărzaru suggest :

[image]

With below code:

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="New Button" />
```

But, if we remove it:

[image]

With below code:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="New Button" />
```

So, my suggest is use your own Style for coloring it like below:

[How to set Style for a button in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070827/how-to-set-style-for-a-button-in-android)

Or, Using `<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#FF9800</item>` in the styles.

And finally, here you can see the good result:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:text="New Button" />
```