# Custom button style on android

Tags: android

I am creating a custom button using the following link. I followed every step.
https://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=3307

Then I created a button the following way :

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnButton1"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:buttonStyle="@style/button"
    android:text="CREATE"
    android:onClick="createButtonClickHandler"/>
```

But I see my button has default style. I expected my button has this new fancy custom style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `buttonStyle` , use just `style`:

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnButton1"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:style="@style/button"
    android:text="CREATE"
    android:onClick="createButtonClickHandler"/>
```

Reference : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: I got the following error when I build my app:  Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'style' in package 'android'

Comment: Then, this question may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070827/how-to-set-style-for-a-button-in-android

Comment: Button maker link helped me to solve my problem partially.