# How styles represented as java classes in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

for example:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    ... />
```

here tag name is `Button` and is represented `Button` class in java classes and each attribute correspond to method name in `Button` class.
In this way we can parse this tag to real object to draw in screen.

but in styles I can't understand which classes represent each style, for example:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Style for a tab that displays a category name -->
    <style name="CategoryTab" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/CategoryTabTextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Text appearance style for a category tab -->
    <style name="CategoryTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textColor">#A8A19E</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I can't find class name `DarkActionBar` or for example `colorPrimary` as method or member class, how can find these tags and it's attribute in correspond java class like Button object? I need clear explanation about what this mean in java classes.

Comment: Its the same concept as JSON, you parse the string meta-data and modify your class according to what is written in the JSON. Other example would be you read a Text file and parse/execute what is written there.

Comment: but in style i can't find class as name of style i found R.style but it does not contain any DarkActionBar class for example

Comment: Because not everything is expressed in a form of class. Sometimes it is enough to use a simpler form like a text. See how CSS use to design in web, it is not repented by a class but a block of attributes and values.

Comment: so how can i read about this tag and know which value expected for its attribute ?

Comment: These designs are implicitly implemented by Android itself but you can also explicitly use your own style in view by using the `style` attribute in View. For more info you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070827/how-to-set-style-for-a-button-in-android).

Comment: ok so i should not be care about how these style represented in java classes?

Comment: yes you don't need.